# PHP blade template live edit with Idea intellij?

Tags: php, laravel, intellij-idea, laravel-blade

Is there any plugin, chrome extension that can be used for live edit (constant browser refresh) when working with Idea IntelliJ on a Laravel project?

What I need is when I edit Blade templates, I want to the browser to refresh automatically without the need for manual pressing (commad+R) or (control + F5)

I am using idea IntelliJ PHP Built-in Web Server
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting this feature, you need to get some service like browserSync running. I think you'll need to use a more real world web server than the build in one, but I'm not sure.

I've had this running by using Laradock locally, once Laradock is set up it's pretty easy to get browswersync running and get live refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** The instructions are *not* dependent on XAMPP. You could use any apache/nginx server setup stack. i.e LAMP to follow along.

This assumes that you're using [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

1. Install XAMPP.
2. Move/set up your project to the `htdocs` folder of XAMPP. (`C:\xampp\htdocs`)

**NOTE:** Moving forward, I'll use `your-project` to mean your actual *project name*.

3. Set up a virtual host for your project. i.e:

   Open the file: `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`

   Then add the tags below at the end of this file:

   ```xml
     <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin steve@steve.com
         DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\your-project\public"
         ServerName local.your-project

         <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
              Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              Allow from all
              Require all granted
         </Directory>
     </VirtualHost>
   ```

   You may change the `ServeAdmin` and `DocumentRoot` as you which.
4. Adjust your `hosts` file to always route to `127.0.0.1` when you access the project from the browser.

   For *"Windows Operating System"* users, you will find the file at:     `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

   Open the `hosts` file and add the line below at the end:

   `127.0.0.1       local.your-project`
5. Ensure that the necessary PHP extensions are enabled/installed to smoothly run your project.

   You may need to remove the preceding `;` characters on the respective lines to enable these extensions.

   For *"Windows Operating System"* users, you will find the configuration file at:     `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

   Open your `php.ini` configuration file and confirm that the extensions below are enabled.

   ```
       ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
       ; http://php.net/extension-dir
       ;extension_dir = "./"
       ; On windows:
       extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"

       extension=bz2
       extension=curl
       extension=fileinfo
       extension=gd
       extension=gettext
       extension=intl
       extension=mbstring
       extension=exif
       extension=openssl
       extension=pdo_mysql
       extension=mysqli
       extension=php_openssl.dll
       extension=php_ftp.dll
   ```

**NOTE:** *All commands below assume that your terminal/command prompt is pointing at your project root directory. i.e: `cd C:\xampp\htdocs\your-project`*

6. Ensure that both *MySQL* and *Apache* services are running.

[image]

7. Set up Laravel mix [with `browserSync`](https://browsersync.io/docs).

**NOTE:** *The commands below assume that [Node.js and NPM](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm) are already installed on your computer.*

Install `browser-sync`

`npm i browser-sync --save-dev`

Install `browser-sync-webpack-plugin`

`npm install browser-sync-webpack-plugin --save-dev`

Install any pending unrun dependencies.

`npm install`

Open the file at `your-project-root-directory\webpack.mix.js`

Add the configuration below at the end of that file.

```javascript
// ...

mix.browserSync({
    port: 8089,
    proxy: {
        target: "http://local.your-project/",
    }

});
```

8. [OPTIONAL]. If you use `sass` in your application, you may wish to include the dependencies below.

`npm install sass-loader sass resolve-url-loader --save-dev`

9. Compile your assets.

`npm run dev`

10. Start watching project file changes.

`npm run watch`

11. At this time, if your browser was already open, your project might have loaded automatically. If that wasn't the case, open your browser and search for this URL. `http://localhost:8089/`

This denotes the `port` you set up while configuring `browserSync`.

12. From this point onwards, `browserSync` will refresh the page automatically whenever you change a project file.

#### Next Steps (Moving Forward)

Whenever you start working on your project, just make sure that both *MySQL* and *Apache* services are running. Then run `npm run watch` in your terminal for `browserSync` to start listening for file changes.

#### Extra resources

[Laravel | Compiling Assets (Mix)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix)

[Laravel | Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/installation)

Comment: No I am not using XAMMP.

Comment: @Adelin, The instructions are not dependent on XAMPP. You could use any apache setup. i.e LAMP to follow along.